# what is the integration of $\int\cot(e^x)\cdot e^x dx$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, trigonometry, exponential-function

what is

$$
\int\cot(e^x)\cdot e^x dx
$$

This is my answer is it right

$$
u=e^x\\
du=e^x dx\\
dx=\frac{1}{e^x}du
$$

Then $$\int\cot(u)\cdot u \frac{1}{u}du=\int \cot(u)\ du=\csc^2(u)$$

Is this answer right

Comment: Don't forget to replace $u$ with $e^x$ and to add a constant of integration. Also, try to learn latex/mathjax. It is difficult for other users to understand the mathematical steps if they are not written in mathjax/latex.

Comment: Where is your formatting?

Comment: A few problems: 1) You didn't integrate $\int\cot u\,du$. You differentiated it and calculated $\dfrac d{du}\cot u$ instead. 2) You didn't come back to using the original variable $x$.

Comment: Your substitution to get to $\int \cot u\ du$ is correct.  Next step $\int \frac {\cos u}{\sin u} \ du$  Now you need another substitution!

Comment: Hint:
$$\int\tan x\,dx=\int\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\,dx=-\ln \cos x+C$$ because the numerator ($\sin x$) is the negative of the denominator ($\cos x$).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen $-\ln | \cos x | + C$, eh?

Comment: If you need a link, here’s the [MathJax tutorial](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your answer is not correct, but you were on the right track for the most part. Your problem was that you were looking at the wrong table when you were taking the integral of $\cot{u}$. Instead of the antiderivate of the cotangent function which is $\int\cot{x}\:dx=\ln{|\sin{x}|}+C$, you used its derivative $\left(\frac{d}{dx}\cot{x}=-\csc^2 x\right)$ to finish off the problem (you also dropped the minus sign for some reason). You got it completely backwards. Anyway, this is a simple integration by substitution (sometimes called u-substitution) problem. Integration by substitution is nothing more than the chain rule done backwards.

$$
\int\cot e^x\cdot e^x dx=\\
u=e^{x}\implies\\
\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}e^{x}\implies\\
\frac{du}{dx}=e^{x}\implies\\
dx=\frac{du}{e^{x}}\\
=\int\cot u\cdot u \frac{du}{u}=
\int\cot{u} du=
\ln{|\sin{u}|}+C=
\ln{|\sin{e^{x}}|}+C
$$

Answer: $\ln{|\sin{e^{x}}|}+C$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\int e^x\cot{e^x}dx=\int\frac{e^x\cos{e^x}}{\sin{e^x}}dx=\int\frac{1}{\sin{e^x}}d(\sin{e^x})=\ln|\sin{e^x}|+C$$

Comment: I think an intermediate step using cot = cos/sin would make this clearer.

Comment: I added it. Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea. Using $u=e^x$, we have $du=e^x\,dx$ so $$\int\cot(e^x)\cdot e^x\,dx=\int\cot u \, du=\int\frac{\cos u}{\sin u}\, du$$ Now let $v=\sin u$. Then $dv=\cos u\, du$ so $$\int\cot u\, du=\int\frac1v\, dv=\ln|v|+C$$ where $C$ is a constant.

Therefore $$\boxed{\int\cot(e^x)\cdot e^x\,dx=\ln|\sin(e^x)|+C}$$